# C structure object member name as parameter

Tags: c++, structure

How can I pass a structure name, object name, different member name(whose value to be verified) as a parameter to a function ?

```
struct st{
    int a;
    int b;
}
bool verify(____ st , ____ b){
    if(obj.b == 5)return true;
    return false;
}
int main(){
   st obj;
   // now that I know all the names of members of struct name
   // HOW can I verify passing different member name as parameter

   cout<<verify(__,__);
}
```

For an instance:
(example with error)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct st{
int a;
int b;
};
bool verify(st obj, st.a val){
if(obj.a==val)
return true;
}
int main()
{
cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
st obj;
cout<<verify(obj,a);
//cout<<verify(obj,b);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't. Use offsets along with the `offsetof()` macro.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: In C++ you can use `std::map` instead of `struct`.

Comment: Is `obj` supposed to be `st`?

Comment: Using a member pointer?

Comment: Don't do this. There are various things you could do with macros that would work but I'm 99.99% sure that if you explained what problem you are trying to solve we would suggest something much much better to do instead.

Comment: Pointer to data member? e.g. `verify(obj, &st::a)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pointer to data member:

```
bool verify(const st &obj, int st::* field) {
    return obj.*field == 5;
}
...
st obj;
std::cout << verify(obj, &st::a);
std::cout << verify(obj, &st::b);
```

But the syntax is confusing and just passing a reference to the data member to verify is easier:

```
bool verify(int field) {
    return field == 5;
}
...
st obj;
std::cout << verify(obj.a);
std::cout << verify(obj.b);
```

Using a template:

```
#include <iostream>

struct st
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
struct st2
{
    int c;
    int d;
};

template<typename T>
bool verify(const T &obj, int T::* field)
{
   return obj.*field == 5;
}

int main()
{
    st obj = {5, 6};
    st2 obj2 = {5, 6};
    std::cout << verify(obj, &st::a) << "\n";    // 1, since obj.a is 5
    std::cout << verify(obj2, &st2::d) << "\n";  // 0, since obj.d is not 5
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is what I wanted, can we make  verify function generic ?
for different structures st1,st2, and different member inside every struct will the same function work ?

Comment: @Jackson You can use a template: `template<typename T> bool verify(const T &obj, int T::* field) { ... }`

Comment: Can you please detail ? the code unable to get through

Comment: @Jackson I've edited my answer with an example using a template